# Getting I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request

Tags: java, optimizely

I have been using optimizely 'core-api', version:'3.3.0' and 'core-httpclient-impl', version:'3.3.0'
for my java app. I frequently see this exception in my info log
**"I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://cdn.optimizely.com: Connection reset"**.
This is logged part of optimizely SDK. I'm not able to find why this shows up as the http calls from the sdk are succeeding. If someone can give me some leads that will be great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the other side or a network component in the line dropped the connection unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your reply. Looks like the server end the connection while still the client was trying to poll for packets.